# Writing a callback function for async c#.net

Tags: c#, asynchronous, kinvey

I am using Kinvey for my storage

The callback for a **non Async** **function** is written as shown

```
myClient.User().create(myUserName, myPassword, new KinveyUserCallback(){...});
```

how do i do it if I was using an **Async** **function** ?

```
myClient.User().createAsync(myUserName, myPassword);
```

Im interested in the `onError` callback to check if the user already exists.

Answer (score 0):

In kinvey's documentation, they clearly stated that:

> If the username does exist, the callback's onError method will be
>   invoked

So when you execute this code:

```
User user = await myClient.User().createAsync(myUserName, myPassword);
```

***if the user already exists***, you will receive the error message inside `onError` function as below.

```
@Override
public void onError(String error) {
     // do something with the error
     // maybe log it and/or throw the error to UI
}
```

Comment: I'm using c#.net with Xamarin there is no override function onError inside the Activity(Parent) class.

Comment: @user3814750: that's weird, the `onError` was there in in their documentation for xamarin (http://devcenter.kinvey.com/xamarin/guides/users). You might want to check all their override-able functions.